# Beforeunload event does not fire after page refresh Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this simple code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--<script src="angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script>       

        window.onload = function () {
            window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
                debugger;
            });
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
                debugger;
            });
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
               
            }
        }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body ng-app="app">   

</body>
</html>
```

I want unload or beforeunload events be fired after I refresh the page. This is not happening in Chrome Versión 67.0.3396.62. I have tried firefox and edge and it works well. It also works when i close the tab. The error ocurrs only when i refresh the page.

Comment: You are not adding the events until after the window has loaded. So take your eventListener's out of the window.onload

Comment: I removed the window.onload. The result is the same.

Comment: could be a bug with that version of chrome?? Maybe try posting to their forum.

Comment: I have the exact same version and the snippet works fine for me

Comment: ok thats really weird @RyanWilson. Did you refresh the page or just close the browser?

Comment: as a workaround, can you use `window.onload` in combination with [`performance.navigation.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type) and check for `TYPE_RELOAD`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've run into an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801975&q=beforeunload&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) that was already reported. It looks like a bug, but according to a [Chrome dev (kozy)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801975#c5) **it is a feature**:

> Thanks for repro. It is actually feature. As soon as you pressed reload we ignore all breakpoints before page reloaded. It is useful all the time when you have a lot of breakpoints and need to reload page to restart debugging session.
>
> Workaround: **instead of pressing reload button you can navigate to the same url using omnibox then all breakpoint will work as expected.**

I've added bold emphasis to point out the workaround proposed by kozy. I've tried it and found that it works.

Other than the issue with the `debugger` statement, the handlers are executed whether you are reloading or closing the tab. In both cases that follow, I get the stock prompt that Chrome provides when returning true:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (ev) {
  ev.returnValue = true; // `return true` won't work here.
});
```

This works too:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return true;
}
```

It used to be that you could use a return value with a message and the browser would show your custom message but browsers generally no longer support this.

Whether or not you want to set the handler for `beforeunload` inside a handler for `load` is *entirely dependent on your goals*. For instance, I have an application for editing documents that does not set the `beforeunload` handler until the application has started initializing, which is much later than the `load` event. The `beforeunload` handler is there to make sure the user does not leave the page with unsaved modifications.

Answer (score 2):

According to [mdn web docs][1]:

> Sticky activation is required. The user has to have interacted with
> the page in order for this feature to work.

You need to interact with page before reloading that is why its working the first time.
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#security

Comment: "it's working" or "it isn't working" the first time?